# Custom view Helper with own view script

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have created my own view helper according to [this](http://zf2dev.com/2013/03/19/how-to-write-custom-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2/) example. The view helper calls my model to create a form. The view Helper returns a form object.

My question is wether it is possible to assign a custom view script to the View Helper for the form. Or should i just use a partial for the script?

Thanks very much

Comment: So you're using a view helper to return a form to the view?

Comment: Correct. It's a comment form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View helpers should be used to *help* construct `HTML` that requires anything more that the normal control logic, the `<?php if ($foo) :` and `<? foreach($foo...`.

You will want to avoid cases where you *view logic* becomes too complex or repetitive, as this results in hard to maintain code.

The example you posted, a `<span>` tag is returned based on the the number of days  (`$numberOfDays`) arguments passed to it. This is something that is most likely repetitive to check every time you wish to output the 'new' item, hence the need for a view helper.

In your case, what would be ideal, would be to fetch the form via the `FormElementManager` from within the **controller**.

```
class FooController {
  function someAction() {
    $serviceManager = $this-getServiceLocator();
    $formElementManager = $serviceManager->get('FormElementManager');
    $myForm = $formElementManager->get('My\Form\Class\Name\Or\Alias'); 

    return new \Zend\View\Model\Model(array(
      'form' => $myForm
    );
  }
}
```

Calling the form from the `FormElementManager` will ensure its dependencies are correctly injected and `init()` called.

In the view you would then render the form using Zend's built in ViewHelpers (Like `FormRow` taking our complex form object and return all the required HTML)

With the above in place the need for you to 'assign view scripts to the form' disappears as the form can be injected, via the controller, into any view script.

Comment: I don't understand why specifically the FormElementManager and not for example the regular way to create the form with builders like over here http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html

Comment: This is to ensure that the instance is created via the service manger. The difference being that init()` is called and the dependencies injected

Comment: As I then have the code to generate a form in one place I also want to have the view scripts in one place. Would I be able to get this done with a view partial?